# finding threshold of activation

Tags: bayesian, binary-data, threshold

Dear crossvalidated community,

I am working on a serie of binary measures $y$ (0s and 1s),  and an environamental variable $x$ (temperature). I suppose the existence of a $\bar x$ that acts like a "switch temperature".
But I do not know how to model this behaviour to infer $\bar x$.

$$
y \sim 0; x < \bar x
$$
$$
y \sim 1; x \geq \bar x
$$

Maybe a logistic regression? I would like to do in in the probabilistic bayesian framework and code it with Stan.